# Thread safe SendAsync / awaitable FIFO

Tags: c#, multithreading, websocket, async-await

So I'm making a thread safe wrapper for `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket`.

What do you think about the following method I came up with, is it thread safe?
The important thing is that only 1 thread at a time executes `_ws.SendAsync` and that waiting threads will execute in FIFO order.

An alternative solution would be to use BlockingCollection and the producer-consumer pattern instead. But BlockingCollection doesn't have the async-await functionality, so I would prefer the current solution if it's thread safe. I'm very thankful for other suggestions as well.

```
private ClientWebSocket _ws;
private int _sendTicketCount = 0;
private int _sendTicketCurrent = 1;

public async Task SendAsync(string message)
{
    if (_ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
        throw new Exception("Connection is not open");

    try
    {
        int mySendTicket = Interlocked.Increment(ref _sendTicketCount);

        if (mySendTicket != _sendTicketCurrent)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => mySendTicket == _sendTicketCurrent)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
        var bytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        await _ws.SendAsync(bytes, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancel.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _sendTicketCurrent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_sendTicketCurrent` needs to be volatile, otherwise the JIT is allowed to cache the value in a register, which could result in an infinite loop. Apart from that, it looks threadsafe except that this is a huge waste of CPU (SpinWait fully uses a core).

Also there is really no point in doing `await Task.Run(() => SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => mySendTicket == _sendTicketCurrent))`. You're gonna hold a thread anyway, so you could do the wait in the current thread.

To do what you want in a more optimized way, there is already an async-compatible synchronization primitive provided out of the box: SemaphoreSlim.

```
private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public async Task SendAsync(string message)
{
    if (_ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
        throw new Exception("Connection is not open");

    try
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
        var bytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
        await _ws.SendAsync(bytes, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cancel.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's nice. I didn't know SemaphoreSlim was awaitable. However I suppose it doesn't guarantee FIFO? Maybe BlockingCollection would be better after all. Or I could replace SpinWait with "While(mySendTicket != _sendTicketCurrent) await Task.Delay(100);" to not waste CPU.

Comment: @remdao Looking at the SemaphoreSlim implementation, the async queue is FIFO. However, the documentation states `If multiple threads are blocked, there is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, that controls when threads enter the semaphore.` so I guess that's no something you should depend on. To ensure FIFO order, I think the easiest/optimal way is to switch to a producer/consumer pattern, using either a BlockingCollection or an AsyncQueue (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncqueue-1?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Answer (score 4):

You have a case of multiple producers and one consumer.

You can do that with an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) set up with the proper option.